# Jain food options in US (Chicago)

Tags: usa, food-and-drink, chicago, dietary-restrictions

I follow a strict Jain diet (i.e. vegetarian with no onion, garlic, potato, or eggs in any food preparation) and would like to follow it in Chicago.
Additionally, if you know any US national food chain (like Subway, taco bell) providing Jain food, let me know

Comment: Is cooking for yourself an option? Because finding restaurants who even understand your requirements (aside from South Asian restaurants) is not going to be easy.

Comment: Doing some research I found one site that says vinegar is not permitted for Jains. If that's true you should include it in your list because many sauces used in American food include vinegar (and some might use turmeric as a colorant). In particular you would need to avoid ketchup, as well as vinaigrette and Italian salad dressings.

Comment: I recommend checking out Yelp.  There are several restaurants listed with reviews mentioning they serve Jain food.  Also, check out The Chicago Diner.  I don't know of specifics, but vegetarian and vegan friends of mine have always liked that place as they will prepare food anyway that you need.

Comment: you might have to stick to Indian restaurants that's what my other Jain friends do

Comment: Did you try Google or Yelp ? https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Jain+Food&find_loc=Chicago%2C+IL The likelihood of any chain serving Jain is basically zero. You will have to deal with individual restaurants and/or self-prepared meals

Comment: Cook for yourself. Will add a skill, save you some bucks and keep you involved.

Comment: Check with the [Jain Society of Metropolitan Chicago](https://jsmconline.org/)? They have a [food court](https://www.clover.com/online-ordering/jsmcfoodcourt).